# Formula to successively reduce list of numbers to get highest number

Tags: probability, algorithms

apologies if this question is ambiguous as I'm not too familiar with stat terms.

Say I have a list of N numbers (all positive). I want to successively delete a % of the lowest numbers in the list, until I only have the highest number in the list.

For example, say I have a list of 100 positive numbers (all different numbers). I want to first delete some x% of the lowest numbers in the list. Than I want to delete some y% of lowest numbers in the new list. And finally delete some z% of lowest numbers in this final list such that I'm only left with the highest number in the list.

Can someone please point me to concepts/formulas that would help me create such a formula?

Comment: Why do you want to successively reduce the list rather than just going through the list once and keeping track of the maximum observed value along the way?

Comment: Im building a game web app, in which users gain points. There are 3 rounds in the game. After the 1st round, I want to delete/terminate the bottom x% of users. Then the game resumes and users continue to accrue points. After the 2nd round finishes, again the bottom %y of users are terminated/deleted. Finally, after the 3rd round, a certain % of bottom users are deleted such that only the highest user or perhaps the 3 highest users are left standing so to speak.

Comment: I want to somehow generalize the formula as I don't know beforehand the actual number of total users that will enter the game.

Comment: [Quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $\frac{x}{100} \times\frac{y}{100} \times \frac{z}{100}=\frac{1}{n}$

You can do this: for the first two rounds, choose whatever percentages you like.

For the last round, you simply want to choose the one (or three) at the top; there's not need to give that as a percentage, but if there were $m$ left after the second culling, the required percentage will be whatever $\frac{100}{m}$ is.

e.g. if you had 25 left going into the last round, 100/25 = 4. If you take the top 4%, that's one person at the top.

Because you don't specify any relationship or conditions relating $x, y $ and $z$, the first two are arbitrary.

Now if you want x, y and z to be related in some way, that changes things.

e.g. if you want x,y and z to be the same, then you want $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{x}{100} \times\frac{y}{100} \times \frac{z}{100}=(\frac{x}{100})^3$

e.g. in that case if you had 1000 people you'd keep $\frac{1}{(1000)^{1/3}}$, or 10% at each stage. ie. 1000$\to$100$\to$10$\to$1

This figure may also be a useful guideline if you want different x y and z since it gives a starting place from which to change the relative sizes of them.